# Building mongo query

Tags: mongodb

I have a model like this:

```
[{item: {
    _id: 123,
    field1: someValue,
    price: {
        [_id: 456,
        field1: anotherValue, 
        type: []],
        [_id: 789,
        field1: anotherValue, 
        type: ['super']]
    }
}]
```

I need to find an item by 3 parameters: `item _id, price _id,` and check if price type array is empty. And check it in one price field.

```
  Model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 123, "price._id": 456, "price.type": {size:0})
```

This query always returns item, cause search in different prices.

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 123, price: {id: 456, type: {size:0})
```

This query returns error (cast array value or something like this).
tried to build query with `$in, $and,` but still getting an error

Comment: are you trying to find or update?

Comment: If find - update, else - do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Use  $elemMatch:

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field
>   with at least one element that matches all the specified query
>   criteria.

```
db.inventory.find({
    price: {
        "$elemMatch": {
            _id: 456,
            type: {
                $size: 0
            }
        }
    }
})
```